# Why do users get an HTTP 404 error when attempting to clone a Mercurial repository over HTTP?

Tags: apache-2.2, http, mercurial, clone

The repository is hosted on my PC. I use Apache with WAMP and TortoiseHG.

I have setup users and passwords and they are able to browse the repository in their browsers after entering their usernames and passwords.

The problem is that, when they try to clone the repository, they get an HTTP404 file note found error.

However, I can clone the repsoitory on my own PC using their credentials.

The problem must lie somehwere with the mercurial setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solved

In the hgweb.cgi file, I replaced:

```
[web]
C:\CentralRepo\ = C:\CentralRepo\
```

with:

```
[paths]
Reports = C:\CentralRepo\Reports\
```

These two are supposed to be alternatives, but only the second option worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is your apache accessible via the web (you can check using google translation services to access your machine)?

Do you use hgweb.cgi? Are there any restrictions set?

I remember that for cloning and pushing you need to explicitely set the permissions for hgweb.cgi. See http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/PublishingRepositories

Comment: Hi @Stephan, I do use hgweb.cgi. Thanks for your response. Please see my answer.

Comment: Great to see that I could be of help in a way :)